# End swap program and display error message if a third number is entered into program. (C)

Tags: c

Ok i need to end swap program and display error message if a third number is entered into program. what do i do? the program has you input 2 numbers and swaps them but how do I make it to where if a third variable is entered an error message is displayed and the program will end. (C)

#include

```
int main() { 
  int x, y; 
  printf("Enter Value of x "); 
  scanf("%d", &x); 
  printf("\nEnter Value of y "); 
  scanf("%d", &y); 

  int temp = x; 
  x = y; 
  y = temp; 

  printf("\nAfter Swapping: x = %d, y = %d", x, y); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: After entering to numbers, the program performs the swap, prints the message and ends... how could it know if/when/whether the user inputted another number afterwards?

Comment: What ——————————